# Hiding page title in wordpress through CSS – Strange behaviour

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to hide the default entry header and the including title on a specific Wordpress page. I know that I should be able to hide it through CSS like this:

```
.page-id-313 .entry-header{
  display: none;
}
```

However, I am only able to make it work if I include empty curly bracket before the CSS code. It looks like this:

```
{}
.page-id-313 .entry-header{
  display: none;
}
```

What is the reason for this behaviour? And should I care?

I am by the way using the Chaplin Theme for my webpage.

Comment: Where are you adding your CSS?

Comment: Are both of those {} brackets needed? Or is it also working when you only have the closing bracket } ?

Comment: @AHaworth I am adding the CSS through Wordpress’s “Additional CSS” functionality under “Customise”.

Comment: @JWGeertsma I have just tested it, and yes, I need both the opening and the closing bracket.

Comment: Have you got any other customised CSS in there? The most likely explanation is that there's a stray character(s) which need 'terminating' in the CSS (e.g. straycharacter {})

Comment: Thank you @AHaworth. You were exactly right. I had a closing bracket without and opening in an earlier CSS addition. The problem is fixed now.